# can't install runit after DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive install -y gcc

Tags: linux, installation, apt, runit, debconf

I hope to install gcc and runnit automatically.
But when I "sudo apt-get install gcc" it comes up a dialog to make choose the configuration.
So I use

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -f -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends gcc
```

and then I use the same way to install runit

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -f -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends runit
```

But unfortunatly Error occur:
It shows

```
start: Unknown job: runsvdir
dpkg: error processing runit (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And my system is a clean Ubuntu10.04 . I can install runit if I don't install gcc noninteractiv.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I have solved this problems. It's beacuse my sources.list is too old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is solved before. Update source.list will be OK